# On evaluation of $\lim_{h\to0} \sqrt[h^2]\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Evaluate the following limit:$$\lim_{h\to0} \sqrt[h^2]\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}$$

> Answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$ as on Wolfram Alpha [query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+h+to+0+%28%281%2Bh%29%5E%281%2Fh%5E2%29%29%2Fe%5E%281%2Fh%29) and evaluated by sympy (Python). Also [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bh%5Cto0%7D%20%5Csqrt%5Bh%5E2%5D%5Cfrac%7B%7B1%2Bh%7D%7D%7Be%5E%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bh%7D%7D%24&p=1) is the math search engine query which returned nothing substantial.

I think the answer is $1$. Why?

If $f(x)\to1$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ then the limit ${f(x)}^{g(x)}=e^{({f(x)-1})\cdot g(x)}$. For those who are curious of the proof:

> $$\lim_{x\to a} [1+(f(x)-1)]^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1} (f(x)-1)g(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} [(1+(f(x)-1))^{\frac{1}{f(x)-1}}]^{\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-1)g(x)}$$

> and then a very popular limit to sum it up $\lim_{x\to0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=e$

Applying the limit on the numerator, we get $e^{\frac{1}{h}}$ which is exactly equal to the denominator. So hence, the answer $1$. Only my close friend desmos supports me here:

[image]

Whereas Wolfram shows

[image]

---

$$\text{My Questions}$$

$1$. Why does the method I adopted shows a speculatively wrong result?

$2$. Is there any way to correct it?

---

Source code for sympy evaluation.

```
#Python 3.8
import math
from sympy import * 
  
x = symbols('x') 
expr = ((1+x)**(1/x**2))/(math.e)**(1/x); 
    
print("Expression : {}".format(expr))  
      
# Use sympy.limit() method  
limit_expr = limit(expr, x, 0)   
      
print("Limit of the expression tends to 0 : {}".format(limit_expr))
```

Run the code:

```
Expression : 2.71828182845905**(-1/x)*(x + 1)**(x**(-2))
Limit of the expression tends to 0 : 0.606530659712633
```

Comment: Getting $e^{1/h}$ as the limit makes no sense, as you take a limit over $h$. And the difference between $(1+h)^{1/h^2}$ and $e^{1/h}$ is important.

Comment: It's actually $f(x)^{g(x)} = e^{g(x)\log f(x)}$ (suitable assumptions are made). For the limit, you get $e^{\lim (f(x)-1)g(x)}$ provided that this limit exists (because $\log f(x) = f(x) - 1 + O\bigl((f(x)-1)^2\bigr)$), but it seems that you split numerator and denominator before taking the limit, which you cannot do here, because the separate limits don't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we have

$$\left(\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}\right)^\frac1{h^2}=\left[\left(1+\left(\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}-1\right)\right)^\frac{1}{\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}-1}\right]^{\frac{\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}-1}{h^2}}$$

with

$$\left(1+\left(\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}-1\right)\right)^\frac{1}{\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}-1} \to e$$

and

$$\frac{\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}-1}{h^2}=\frac1{e^h}\frac{1+h-e^h}{h^2} \to -\frac12$$

Comment: Bonita! Nice proof...So, ${f(x)}^{g(x)}=e^{({f(x)-1})\cdot g(x)}$ cannot be carelessly generalised..

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Yes we need to pay attention to adopt the proper $f(x)$.

Comment: Always thank you for your math support...sometimes on my questions.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question see Daniel's comment. To get W|A's answer we just need L'Hopital:$$\lim_{h\to0}\left(\frac{1+h}{e^h}\right)^{1/h^2}=\exp\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\log((1+h)/e^h)}{h^2}=\exp\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{e^h}{1+h}\cdot\frac{-h}{e^h}}{2h}=\frac1{\sqrt e}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$A= \sqrt[h^2]\frac{{1+h}}{e^h}\implies \log(A)=\frac 1{h^2}\left( \log(1+h)-h\right)$$ Now, by Taylor
$$\log(A)=\frac 1{h^2}\left(-\frac{h^2}{2}+\frac{h^3}{3}+O\left(h^4\right) \right)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{h}{3}+O\left(h^2\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}+\frac{h}{3 \sqrt{e}}+O\left(h^2\right)$$

Comment: I recently looked up a few of your answers on limits...looks like you use series expansions a lot (eg. this one as well)....So a tiny query: Do you remember all the series expressions (the non standard ones too? OR you derive them at the moment? OR you use a computer program like scipy? (Or some blackmagic \*_\*)

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi. Thanks for having taken the time for reading some of my answers. Yes, I use systematicall series not only for limits but mainly for asymptotics. At my age (~80), I know quite many. Thirty plus years ago, I wrote a program to generate them. Now, I use CAS. SInce I solve a lot of equations, I need starting guesses and a series is very useful to have them.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know CAS is new for me, will have a look. I used to rely only on available series and would modify them. Yes, I read a lot of your answers quite recently. You wrote a program in 1990's....wow! back when we had low level languages, that's amazing. Have a good day! I am ~1/4th your age btw... :)

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi. I started with computers in 1960

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you are familiar with L'Hospital's Rule for evaluating limits.

Applying the formula which you mentioned in the question,
$$lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{-h}(1+h) - 1}{h^2} = \frac{-1}{2}$$
by the application of L'Hospital's Rule.

So the final limit is $\frac{1}{\sqrt(e)}$

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the $\text{My Questions}$ tab. I know the methods to evaluate the question.

Comment: Also, (-1) for duplicacy with Simplifire's answer